# Sending an email once every 3 months in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey that sends an email to a client every time he visited a station. So I want to make this mail sent once every 3 months.
how can I do within my journey builder?
this is a screenshot of the journey I[image] want to send it once every 3 months

thank you 
regards

Answer (score 1):

We are achieving this by storing Journey entrants in a Data Extension that contains the date they entered the journey.

Every morning when the Journey (Automation Studio Entry) runs, a SQL query compares the "past entrants" Data Extensions for records from the last 90 days against the "new entrants", and excludes new entrants (who appear of the past entrants list) from re-entering. Once 90 days have past since they entered the Journey, the query activity will no longer select/match the customer for exclusion, thus allowing them to re-enter the Journey.

Intermediate knowledge of SQL, Automation Studio and Journey Builder entry events is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I cannot add comments so replying here.

It is not possible in Journey or you have to create long time journey and wait for 3 months in each email.

This can be achieved this using Automation Studio.

Comment: How can I do it using Automation Studio?